# Taking a screenshot on failed scenario Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, watir

I'm attempting to take a screenshot on failed scenario. I have this in my hooks.rb file

```
After do |scenario|
    if scenario.failed?
        filename = "error-#{@current_page.class}-#{Time.now}.png" 
        @current_page.save_screenshot(filename)
        embed(filename, 'image/png')
    end
  @browser.close
end
```

but i get this error when it attempts to take a screenshot

```
undefined method `save_screenshot' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: How are you setting @current_page?

Comment: Is @current_page perhaps out of scope once you get to the afterhook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can happens in case of use of scenario outline, try to check whether scenario is scenario outline or not before taking a screenshot:

```
After do |scenario|
   if scenario.respond_to?('scenario_outline') then
        scenario = scenario.scenario_outline
   end
   if scenario.failed?
       filename = "error-#{@current_page.class}-#{Time.now}.png" 
       @current_page.save_screenshot(filename)
       embed(filename, 'image/png')
   end
@browser.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
@browser.driver.save_screenshot(filename)
```

It will take a screenshot of the page the browser instance is on when the scenario fails.

You might get another error because @current_page is also used in setting your filename. You can either change how you're defining the filename or with more information we can fix the @current_page issue.